# Automated Quickbook Integration

Tags: php, quickbooks

I have a site where customers can place online orders. I want that whenever a order is placed a invoice is also added in Quickbook for the placed order.

I have installed QuickBooks PHP DevKit (https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php) at http://res-pos.com/quickbooks-php/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/ but the problem with it is that i need be connected with Quickbooks using the "Connect to QuickBooks" button manually.

In my scenario i need it automated so that there would be no need to connect manually.

Comment: Check out: http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_web_connector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are totally misunderstanding how OAuth works and haven't read Intuit's documentation (or, for that matter, any other OAuth documentation).

You need to connect to QuickBooks manually *ONCE* and *only ONCE!*

After you've connected *once* you *never ever ever need to connect manually ever again!*

Connect once, and be done with it, and then it's all automated from there on out.

Comment: This means if i connect once then i can communicate with QuickBook forever.

In page http://res-pos.com/quickbooks-php/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/ when i click "connect to Quickbooks" button a pop-up appears and it gives the following error. Previoulsy it was working correctly and was able to connect and then can add a customer using http://res-pos.com/quickbooks-php/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/example_customer_add.php

Oops! An error has occurred.
Please close this window and try again.
Error Code: internal_error
Message: Error getting application from request token

Comment: Works fine for me - I just went there and connected my QuickBooks Online company. If you're still having trouble, start a new topic and post your code.

Comment: Thanks. It is working now. Not sure what happened before. Do i ever need to reconnect to QuickBook.

Comment: Read the documentation: https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0053_auth_auth/oauth_management_api    You can auto renew them after 180 days with the RENEW API call.

Comment: Thanks for the link. We want to use QuickBook for a webbased product. Every new customer will have a separate instance (created automatically) of the product having a separate database and domain name. Please let me know what would be best process of integrating Quickbook for our product. Do we need to create a IPP developer APP Profile for every new customer.

Comment: You should have ONE app profile registered with Intuit. Because OAuth requires a single, common URL for the OAuth endpoint, you'll have to have a common domain name you use for all of the initial OAuth QuickBooks connections (e.g. quickbooks.your-domain.com). All connections should take place on that domain, and then you can forward your users over to their own domain (their-name.your-domain.com) after they get connected to QuickBooks.

Comment: Thanks. Let me know how can i do initial OAuth QuickBooks connections for new user using the same setup at http://res-pos.com/quickbooks-php/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/

Each user will have his own QuickBook Online account or the same account can be used by all new users. Please give details on this.

Also, let me know if there is any limit on the number of connections per app profile.

Comment: Please reply to my last comment

Comment: Set $the_tenant variable in the code to YOUR unique identifier for each company within your app. Run through the connection process for each tenant. If you publish, there is no limit.